# AJAX request always return the same (Laravel)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to obtain all data from a table named "fases".

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMgh1.png)

That's how i'm listing it. With "cards".

On the button "Fase", i'm trying to obtain a specific "fase" and then, edit it. 
It works pretty well, except when i trying to edit the another "fase", distinct to the first one.
The controller always returns the data of the first one.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-warning" 
                                data-toggle="modal" 
                                data-target="#modalfases" 
                                onclick="consultarFase({{$fase->id}})">
                                Fase
</a>
```

This is my called JavaScript function "consultarFase()"

```
consultarFase = (Identificador) => {
  $.ajax({
    url : window.location+"/get_editar_fase",
    async: true,
    data: {id_fase:Identificador},
    success: function(response){
      response = $.parseJSON(response);
      $('#id_fase_modal').val(response.id);
      $('#nombre_fase_modal').val(response.nombre);
      $('#descripcion_fase_modal').val(response.descripcion);
      $('#fecha_limite_fase_modal').val(response.fecha_limite);
    },
    error: function(response){
      alert("Algo salió mal... vuelve a intentarlo");
    }
  });
}
```

This is the code on the controller:

```
public function getEditarFase($request){
    $fase = AlumnoDao::getFaseById($request);
    return json_encode($fase);
}
```

And its Dao's method:

```
public static function getFaseById($id){
    $fase = DB::table('fase')
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->first();
    return $fase;
}
```

In web.php file, this is the route:

```
Route::get('/alumno/proyectos/{id_proyecto}/get_editar_fase','AlumnoController@getEditarFase')->name('alumno.getEditarFase');
```

In "consultarFase()" i tried to print "identificador" in console.log; It changes.

if i want to edit the first one, it prints "1"
if i want to edit the second one, it print "2" (Its ID's)

But not the controller... it just doesn't works

Comment: Try this
`public function getEditarFase($request){
    $fase = AlumnoDao::getFaseById($request->json('id));
    return json_encode($fase);
}
`

Comment: Still doesn't works :(
Thanks anyway

Comment: Just replace `$request->json('id)` in @JavlonbekSharipov's code with   `$request->get('id_fase')`

Answer (score 0):

```
 type: "get"
```

Add this type method to ajax request, then check.

Answer (score 0):

It was the getEditarFase function. 
Its parameters

```
public function getEditarFase(Request $request){
    $fase = AlumnoDao::getFaseById($request->id_fase);
    return json_encode($fase);
}
```

The "Request" class.